# Get stories with title containing "Testing" in it via 2.0rc1

Tags: rally

Is it possible to get the stories with title containing text "Testing" in it by using filters ?

eg  1. Mobile Testing
    2. Testing Smartphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `contains` operator:

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
            model: 'UserStory',
            fetch: ['FormattedID','Name'],
            autoLoad: true,
            filters:[
                    {
                        property: 'Name',
                        operator: 'contains',
                        value: "Mobile"
                    }

                ],
            listeners: {
                load: this._onDataLoaded,
                scope: this
            }
        });
```